# Run Flyway Migrations via Percona Toolkit

Tags: mysql, database-migration, flyway, percona

I'm looking into setting up FlywayDB as our migration toolkit for our webapp, however there are some migrations (such as adding a column) on large tables (90 million rows) that take many minutes to run.

Usually when this is the case we use Percona Toolkit to run the schema change as it allows the application to continue running and not block incoming queries. So my question is if there a way to run FlywayDB migrations through Percona Toolkit or something similar? I have been unable to find much if any real documentation on such a situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct integration to Percona Online Schema Change from external sources. You would have to code hooks into FlywayDB to execute PT-OSC for you during deployments/migrations or you can write a plugin for PT-OSC to read FlywayDB files.